# How to deserialize a serialized object in scala, in python

Tags: python, scala

I'm new to Scala and I've serialized some information in my Scala code with

Base64.getEncoder().encode(MyByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray)

and I've saved them to a file which will be read by a Python code, but I don't know how to encode them there. 
I've tried reading the file and using filestr.decode('utf-8') but that just returns the byte arrays.

Sorry if this is too much of a naive question.

Comment: If you encoded a byte array, you will get a byte array when you decode it. What type of data is the original data?

Comment: If you want to serialize values that work on different languages, you are likely to want to look into common protocols like CBOR or Protobuf, in your particular example, it looks like you are just serializing a byte array which is encoded into base64, in python, you can just read the file, decode the base64 and you'll have the byte array back.

Comment: the original data currently is a string but it's practically a log of all the data generated in the scala code

Comment: I used base64.standard_b64decode("") on the coded data and it worked, although the output needs trimming, Thanks so much!